# How to show the client-area of another application as a control of mine within Delphi?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, user-interface

I have an application A, whose UI is already in hand.

And I prepare to develop a new application B. When user clicks one of B's buttons, what should be shown is the same of the main-frame of A's.

If I can embed A's client-erea as a control of B, then I can reuse A's binary, not A's code.

But is there a way to realize this technology in Delphi?

Comment: "A, whose UI is already in hand" - Written by you or another?

Comment: It isn't going to work out if these are separate processes.

Comment: @MartynA Yes, written by me. But I don't want to review the code. I want an easy way to integrate the function, or the UI.

Comment: @David I know it is not easy. But I always think, if, if someone has someway...(:

Comment: Will, since you have the source code of A, simplest would be to integrate it into B and maybe provide a button or something in B to create A on demand and display it.  You could even have the main form of A hosted in the main form of B.  Etc.  If you want to integrate the function (but keep A out of sight while the user uses B), then convert A to a COM server that publishes the functionality you want.

Comment: Btw, that means that your q is probably too broad at the moment, because the options I mentioned are really quite different programming topics.

Comment: Sounds like you've made up your mind to use separate processes already. Since you've decided what you are doing, how can we help? In other words if you aren't interested in our advice, what have we to offer?

Comment: @MartynA thanks for your advices, I would consider which way is the easiest.

Comment: @David I agree. Not everything I can imagin can be possible. Something only can be imagined for a while.

Comment: ActiveX is the platform supported solution for binary interop of UI components

Comment: @David That's interesting. If I have no need to touch the old code, then a lot of time is saved. But wish some simple example be offered.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. You keep asking for a magic solution. A handful of lines of code that embeds one app into another in a seamless way. You should be concerning yourself with a design that will actually work and then evaluate how much effort will be involved. Adding constraints like "no changes to app A" are artificial and pointless. What's important to you? Doing no work, or having a solution that actually works? Your boss won't be happy when you say, "My solution doesn't work, but it cost nothing."

Comment: It doesn't look as though you've done any [websearch](http://www.google.com/search?q=embed+window+process+setparent&hl=en-GB) So you might have success with SetParent and AttachThreadInput and message loop pre-processing. But it's not easy.

Comment: Oh my god, I really suspect that perhaps that if you can conceive then you can do it.

Comment: My advice is to keep UI in the same process. But hey, what do I know?

Comment: Raymond offers the same advice http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx